Feedback and Gand-Bandwidth Question
I am simulating the closed-loop frequency responses for two resistive feedback amplifier circuits.
The opamps used in both circuits are ideal and identical. The two feedback circuits only differ by the input resistance with one being 5k and the other 50k (to make voltage gains of 20 and 2).
Circuit 1: Rin = 5k, Gain = 20V/V.

Circuit 2: Rin = 50k, Gain = 2V/V.

This was the simulation result for the two circuits. The red curve is the ideal opamp open-loop response. The yellow is the closed-loop response with the gain of 20V/V. The green is the closed-loop response with the gain of 2V/V.
In feedback theory, when feedback is applied, the closed-loop gain is (1+AB) factor smaller than the open-loop gain, where A is the open-loop gain and B is the feedback factor. The 3dB bandwidth will extend by a factor of (1+AB). Hence, for a one-pole system, the unity-gain frequency should remain constant. However, from the simulation, I notice that with a larger feedback factor, the unity-gain frequency tends to be lower and to not follow the original open-loop unity-gain frequency. This can be seen from the green curve.
I'm wondering why this is the case. Could you please show me the reason behind it?
Thank you very much


Not a full answer, but think about how the voltage dividers look when you assume that the OpAmp's output is zero (or close to zero).

In feedback theory, when feedback is applied, the open-loop gain will decrease by a factor of (1+AB) <-- no, the open loop gain remains the open-loop gain.

@Andyaka Thank you very much for your reply. Sorry for the confusion. I was meant to express the idea of A/(1+AB). Maybe I should say "closed-loop gain is (1+AB) factor smaller than the open-loop gain" instead?  What do you think?

Yes that sounds better.

Hi Andy, Thank you very much. I have edited my original post to correct the statement.


I notice that with a larger feedback factor, the unity-gain frequency tends to be lower and to not follow the original open-loop unity-gain frequency. This can be seen from the green curve. I'm wondering why this is the case.

It doesn't have to be a differential output amplifier to see this effect. Consider a regular op-amp with an open loop gain of 100,000 like this one I created in micro-cap below: -

I've made the input resistor unfeasibly small just to reproduce an open-loop response similar to yours: -

As you can see it has a DC gain of 100 dB that becomes unity a little over 10 MHz. If I increase my variable, R3 to 5 kΩ we see this: -

Hopefully you can see that the closed loop response isn't quite reaching the open-loop response. It's more obvious if I make R3 progressively higher: -

The reason is this; you have implemented an inverting amplifier that potentially can have a closed-loop gain that is zero and, the more you reduce the closed-loop gain, the more it just cannot reach the open-loop response. If you'd have implemented a non-inverting amplifier you would see what you expected i.e. no "fall-away" from the open-loop response at high frequencies: -


Hi Andy, Thank you very much for your help. I'm sorry, but I still don't quite understand why, when the closed-loop gain can potentially be very small (close to zero like the inverting amplifier case), the closed-loop response cannot reach the original open-loop response. Could you please explain it to me a little more? Thank you very much

Take the extreme case of the gain being zero. How can there be any amplification at all so, how could the closed loop gain (zero) ever hope to be anything other than zero at any frequency @Kenlucius

Hi Andy, Thank you very much. I understand it now. May I please restate it in my own words and let you see if I have understood the concept right? When the closed-loop gain can potentially be zero (like the inverting amplifier case), the closed-loop response will deviate away from the open-loop response as it tends to zero (gets smaller). It makes intuitive sense because when the closed-loop gain = 0, it shouldn't have any other value at any frequency. For closed-loop gain not able to reach zero (non-inverting case), the closed-loop response will follow the opamp response at high frequencies.

@Kenlucius that sounds reasonable. Maybe I might change this: the closed-loop response will deviate away from the open-loop response as it tends to zero to at high frequencies, low value closed-loop responses can never merge with the open-loop response

Hi Andy, Thank you very much for your help. I sincerely appreciate it :)
